# ng-options doesn't work angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Factory:

```
(function(){
    angular
    .module('projectApp')
    .factory('weatherfactory', weatherfactory);

    weatherfactory.$inject=['$http'];

    function weatherfactory($http){
    var cities=[
      {name: "Łódź", link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?  q=Lodz&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"},
      {name: "Warszawa", link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Warszawa&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"},
      {name: "Wrocław", link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Wroclaw&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"},
      {name: "Kraków", link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Krakow&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"},
      {name: "Gdańsk", link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Gdansk&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"},
      {name: "Londyn", link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"}
    ];
    var weat={};

    var service={
      getCities: getCities,
      GetWeather: _GetWeather
    };
    return service;

    function _GetWeather(link){
      return $http.get(link);
    }


    function getCities(){
      return cities;
    }
  }
})();
```

In controller i get data from factory:

```
sa.cities=weatherfactory.getCities();
```

And in view i am trying to show data in  but it does'n work:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item.name as item.link for item in sa.cities"></select>
```

I am using controllerAs approach.

Comment: show some more code..some of points are not cleared..are you using `controllerAs` approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-options` requires `ng-model` to be specified:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="something" ng-options="item.name as item.link for item in sa.cities"></select>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  var sa = this;
  sa.cities = [{
    name: "Łódź",
    link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Lodz&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"
  }, {
    name: "Warszawa",
    link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Warszawa&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"
  }, {
    name: "Wrocław",
    link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Wroclaw&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"
  }, {
    name: "Kraków",
    link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Krakow&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"
  }, {
    name: "Gdańsk",
    link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Gdansk&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"
  }, {
    name: "Londyn",
    link: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=pl"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController as sa'>
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.name as item.link for item in sa.cities"></select>
</div>
```